# How does running one virtual machine on a host system will reduce system performance?

Tags: operating-system, virtualization, virtual-machine

I am running one virtual machine on a host system, with 50% memory and 50% CPU allocated to it.

Will this reduce the system performance by half?

Give me your comments and suggestions.

Comment: Just a hint - you might get better answers asking this at http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/. A good question though.

Comment: It depends on the VM workload. If it's idle or lightly loaded, it could be less than half. If it's doing lots of I/O and calculations, it could be more than half.

Answer (score 2):

Alex is correct. The reason that it could take less than half of your system performance, is because most virtualization systems will not dedicate precisely that amount of CPU and memory to your virtual machine if the software running inside the VM is not demanding that much. If the VM is running a demanding workload though, this will not be the case.

The reason that it could take more than half of your system performance is because any virtualization system has its own overhead, just in order to provide the virtualization to the VM. Some memory is consumed in tracking the memory and resources used by the virtual machine, and some CPU is consumed in handling the needs of the VM (interrupts from network traffic, etc.).